# Is there any way to get a permanent image URL of a Facebook post?

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am attempting to save the URL of the thumbnail pictures of public Facebook posts such as https://www.facebook.com/sulittechreviews/photos/959579297837445?photo.

However, the only image URL that I can get so far is this:

> https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/107700240_959579301170778_1171082264252632018_o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=MjTu1mTYD8IAX-pHtKy&_nc_ht=scontent.fsin9-1.fna&oh=54e579245f03405e44b437fe02cbf050&oe=5F35A94

which is evidently not good because any CDN URLs will expire after some time (which has happened to me once already).

I am looking for a permanent dynamic URL which will allow me to access the picture of these public Facebook posts but I haven't been able to find one so far. Has anyone managed to find a solution to this? There have been numerous solutions to saving the profile picture of a public user but not many so far for saving the thumbnail of a public post by a public Facebook page.

Comment: The `photo` node has a `picture` edge same as the user node - but it will only return a 100px wide thumbnail. There is nothing else besides that, as far as I can see - you will either have to store that image on your own system, or make an API request to get a current, valid CDN URL whenever you need one.

Comment: The only problem with using Facebook's graph API for `photo` node is that it requires an access token in order to get that thumbnail, which is something I'm avoiding for now. Thanks for your advice though :(

Comment: @CBroe Would you care to visit my question regarding similar issue? How can I get a permanent CDN URL of an image from my Facebook page? Thanks!